# Is there an extension for better UI when writing formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets-formula

Formulas in google sheets are always written out as on line. This makes it tedious to quickly understand them. Like when you are programming you use linebreak to make things more understandable. Is there an extension that auto structure formulas or something like that?

Short example. The following formula:

```
=TRIM(if(LEN(A141)>10,PROPER(A141),LOWER(A141)))
```

And the extension makes it look like this or something similar:

```
=TRIM(
  if(LEN(A141)>10,
    PROPER(A141),
    LOWER(A141)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, there isn't, but you can always achieve it manually by pressing <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`ENTER`**</kbd> and inserting line breaks where you wish it

```
=TRIM(
      IF(LEN(A141)>10, 
                       PROPER(A141), 
                       LOWER (A141)
      )
 )
```

[image: 0]